# A lot of Huawei tags have been created recently

Tags: discussion, tags

If you look at the tags created recently you'll see this:

[image]

It seems like a lot of these questions have been asked and answered by the same people. Here's an example:

- [HMS Nearby Service-Why does the BeaconManager app report status code 502 or 401?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61925643/1244884)
- [An error is reported when HUAWEI Drive Kit is used to query the file list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61996537/1244884)
- [When I test an app integrated with the HMS Health Kit on my Huawei Mate 30 Pro, why cannot I obtain the number of steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62001567/1244884)
- [HMS Awareness Kit-Error code 10011 is returned after the SDK is integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62034152/1244884)
- [An error occurs when HUAWEI Scan Kit executes the startScanFromFragment method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62021393/1244884)

Comment: I got rid of all these tags and double-checked that the questions already had huawei-mobile-services. There's a very slim chance that this is a voting ring but I view it as unlikely, it seems that the tag is just small.